# Firebase Hosting hosted website with custom domain not loading with www prefix

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I own a domain through GoDaddy with the `.app` extension (call it `mydomain.app`). I have a site hosted on Firebase Hosting for this domain and it works fine. However, the website only loads through `https://mydomain.app` and not `https://www.mydomain.app`. I have the DNS properly configured according to GoDaddy tech support and wonder if I'm supposed to explicitly add `www.mydomain.app` in Firebase hosting *in addition to* `mydomain.app`? Seems redundant. Or is this not necessary and I have a configuration problem on my hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to GoDaddy, where you added your A record to point to Firebase the first time.
Since it's working, that means you configured it to use
`@ ==> your FirebaseAppUrl`.

Under it, now, add also another A record, to configure your [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com),
by adding `www` A record, to point to the same place.
`www ==> your FirebaseAppUrl`.

Keep both records of course in GoDaddy.